# Why does a box shadow flicker on transition when a standard shadow does not?

Tags: html, css

Why does an inset box shadow flicker during a transition? It does not shake when I remove inset.

[Codepen.io demo](https://codepen.io/Mengo/pen/RwwaGdp)

```
.main-nav li{
    padding: 15px 20px;

}

.slide{
    transition: .25s;
}

.slide:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 teal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this bug on my own website in Chrome 79.0.3945.79

When using Firefox Developer Edition and Edge I did not run into this problem, the problem also doesn't occur on resolutions below 3410px, the height does not have any effect on this...

Edit:

After testing some more I found that you can fix this by changing the width of the parent element. Whereas my statement of 3410px is false, this just happened to be matching.